# Make fixed page elements "honor" the body right padding?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My fixed button triggers a menu. While menu is opened, the body has `overflow-y: hidden` and a `padding-right: 17px` (actually this value is computed, omitted for brevity). The button (`position: fixed`) is shifted.

The HTML (the `<p>` is only needed to show the scrollbar):

```html
<body>
  <button class="btn">
    Menu
  </button>
  <p style="height: 5000px;"></p>
</body>
```

To the CSS... note that `.menu-opened` is added when you click the button, via JavaScript:

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

body.menu-opened {
  padding-right: 17px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

/* Useless styles */
.btn {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 1rem;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

[Example pen here](https://codepen.io/gremo/pen/poaYBwr)

As soon as the scrollbars are disabled, button is shifted because fixed elements doesn't honor the body padding (which is added to compensate the absence of the scrollbar). Any idea on how to solve this, without touching all fixed elements?

I think this is a common problem, so there should be an easy solution, but I can't get it.

[image: Fixed elements shifted]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Your question won't close if you improved enough your question (or reopen if you improve it later). By the way you should add your code in a snippet rather than using an external site.

Comment: Also, we don't know how your menu should look like since it's empty so it's hard to meet your expectations.

Comment: @Cédric how the menu looks like is irrelevant. IThe question is about the fixed positioned element "shifted" when a padding is added to the body, and the scrollbar is disabled. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `scrollbar-gutter`: [MDN: scrollbar-gutter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter)

Comment: Doesn't work as intended. Ok the layout doesn't shift (i don't need the padding-right anymore) but fixed elements still shift :( thanks for the idea, +1